# Finding pair arrangement in Go

Tags: algorithm, go, pattern-matching

Here I'm trying to form an arrangement that contains pairs of numbers that each pair of *m's* are separated by *m* elements. for example:

- for [0,2], the pair arrangement is [2,0, 0,2] such that m=2, hence    the number 2 is separated by 2 elements.
- for [0,1] = there is no valid arrangement

I still can't figure out the pattern or algorithm for the arrangement as I need to find the arrangement up to [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]. however the valid arrangement for this list is [3,7,8,2,3,1,2,1,6,7,5,8,4,0,0,6,5,4] by doing it manually.

In the codes below, I could only rearrange the numbers in the list by getting the largest number in the list first. I want to know how to separate the pair according to the number of the pair (e.g if the pair is 2, hence separation number is 2)

how can i do the separation and pattern for the list of numbers?

```
    package main

    import "fmt"

    func MagicPairs(list []int) {
        //length := len(list) * 2
        magicPair := []int{}
        magicPair = append(list, list...)

        for i := 0; i <len(magicPair); i++{
            if len(magicPair) == 0 {
                //do nothing
            }else{  
                m := max(list)
                for p, x := range magicPair{
                    if magicPair[len(magicPair)-1] == m {   
                        magicPair = append([]int{m}, (magicPair)[:len(magicPair)-1]...)
                        fmt.Println(magicPair)
                        return
                    }
                    if x == m{
                        magicPair = append([]int{m}, append((magicPair)[:p], (magicPair)[p+1:]...)...)
                    }

                    previousPair := magicPair[x]
                    if x == previousPair{

                    }

                }
            }
        }
        fmt.Println("1", magicPair)
    }

    func max(list[] int) int{
        max := list[0]
        for _, value := range list{
            if value > max {
                max = value 
            }
        }
        return max
    }

    func main(){
        list := [] int {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
        MagicPairs(list)

    }
```

Comment: dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58365929/compute-arrangement-of-distinct-elements#comment103227567_58365929

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to try to find the optimal solution by doubling up the source list and then shuffling the numbers around by repeatedly slicing and concatenating the array.

I think this problem lends itself to a recursive approach. Create thze target array with `2 * len(list)` empty slots. (Whether a slot is empty or not must be marked with a special value, for example `-1`.) Then recursively try to fit the elements of the original array into the target array.

Let's look at your example {0, 1, 3}. Create the target array:

```
. . . . . .
```

Try all possible poitions for the 0. The first is

```
0 0 . . . .
```

Now try to fit the 1. There are two possibilities

```
0 0 . . . .
0 0 1 . 1 .
```

but that won't accomodate the next element, 3. Go back one step:

```
0 0 . . . .
0 0 . 1 . 1
```

The 3 won't fit in here, either. We've exhausted our search for that position of zeros, so let's take the next viable position of zeros:

```
. 0 0 . . .
```

There's only one way to place the one:

```
. 0 0 . . .
. 0 0 1 . 1
```

Now let's try to fit the 3 and, bingo!, it fits:

```
. 0 0 . . .
. 0 0 1 . 1
3 0 0 1 3 1
```

Now you can stop the search or try to find other solutions. In this case, there's only one other solution, namely the reflection of this one, but there are 300 ways to place the numbers from 1 to 8, foe example.

That approach is pretty much brute force, but in practice, there aren't many valid ways to fill the array, so that wrong paths are detected early. Perhaps placing the big numbers first gives better performance. You can play with that and measure it.

Here's a program that does that. (It probably looks more like C than Go. never mind.)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func fit_r(res[] int, a[] int, i int) int {
    n := len(a);

    if i == n {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", res);
        return 1;
    } else {
        count := 0;
        m := a[i];

        for j := 0; j < 2*n - 1 - m; j++ {
            if res[j] == -1 && res[j + 1 + m] == -1 {
                // place values
                res[j] = m;
                res[j + 1 + m] = m;

                // test further values
                count += fit_r(res, a, i + 1);

                // clean up and remove values again
                res[j] = -1;
                res[j + 1 + m] = -1;
            }
        }        

        return count;
    }
}

func fit(a[] int) int {
    res := make([] int, 2 * len(a));

    for i := range res {
        res[i] = -1;
    }

    return fit_r(res, a, 0);
}

func main() {
    list := [] int {0, 1, 2, 3};
    n := fit(list);

    fmt.Println(n, "solutions");
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for these!! it works! it is exactly what I was looking for and I have been struggling with this. I really appreciate the help. But may I know why is it res[j + 1 + m] and j < 2*n - 1 - m?

Comment: You always place a "magic" pair with distance `m`, where `j` is the position of the left number and `j + 1 + m` is the poition of the right number. The right number must not go beyond the array bounds at `2*n`, hence the loop condition `j < 2*n - 1 - m`.

Comment: Oh okay! I totally get it now. Thank you so much! may I know what could possibly be the O-notation/performance for this solution? is it O(n)^2? derived by the two for loops?

Comment: Good question. The upper bound is certainly O(n²) and you can get it with input like {0, 0, 0}.